# remove_ids through c++ interface in faiss

Tags: indexing

I need some c++ examples about how to remove ids through c++ interface! thanks!

```
faiss::IndexFlatL2 index(d);           
printf("is_trained = %s\n", index.is_trained ? "true" : "false");
index.add(nb, xb);                   
faiss::IDSelectorRange ids(0,5);
long nremove = 0;
index.remove_ids(ids, nremove);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`remove_ids` takes an `IDSelector` object. The `IDSelectorRange` removes all elements between two ids.

To remove a list of ids, use `IDSelectorBatch` with a table of ids to remove.

See https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/blob/master/AuxIndexStructures.h#L78 for some documentation.